# Some keyboard keys work only after multiple keystrokes

Tags: keyboard, hardware-failure, keystrokes

The keys <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>`</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> start working only after multiple keystrokes on these keys.

Everywhere I have read about this it says it is a problem with the keyboard. I don't know what to say because after multiple strokes on any of them they start working for a while.
 Hoping I can find a fix for this.

Comment: Do you have access to another keyboard that you can try on the computer to isolate the problem? Is this on a laptop?

Comment: Yes, I do have access to another keyboard, I tried, and that one works just fine. It's not a laptop. Didn't try this keyboard on another computer though, I failed to mention that all this started once I installed windows 10(didn't think it was worth mentioning, I thought about this now because I noticed once I upgraded my machines to windows 10 the num-lock is toggled off at the login screen when you start the computer).

Comment: I guess you are checking the original keyboard on another computer right now? Does the keyboard use any sort of driver software, or is it just an ordinary one? Has it had any liquids spilt on it - that it is mostly keys on the left suggests that one of the circuits in the keyboard (they often use a matrix layout electrically) is slightly damaged. Have you tried turning the keyboard upside-down and shaking any loose bits out of it?

Comment: What is the brand and model of your keyboard?

Comment: The driver is standard plug-and-play type for basic keyboard usage(if I want to use specific features it requires separate drivers, which I have installed, the keyboard is a Logitech G15v1). It hasn't had any liquid spilled on it since I bought it. Found the issue, I checked it on another computer, it turns out to be a keyboard related issue, thanks for the help anyway.